# react native How to control when to prompt user for push notification permissions in IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, react-native-ios

I'm looking a way to control in **react native** when to prompt user for push notification permission in IOS and if there is way to get any callback if user presss allow or deny for prompt.
[image]

Comment: if you have implemented notification in ios then it will prompt alert when app open there is nothing you can do

Comment: I didn't implement, it by default in ios when I give permission to push noitification

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm). If you use [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/), you can prompt users to give permission so, as follows:

```
firebase.messaging().hasPermission()
  .then(enabled => {
    if (enabled) {
      // user has permissions
    } else {
      // user doesn't have permission
    } 
  });
```